# How do I create a number pad as a control?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Pretty new to windows phone development...

I'm trying to create an input view that contains a number pad for inputting a sales amount. I know that if you were inputting a number into a text box, you can set the input scope to numeric and then when you click in the text box, a number pad will come up but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I quite literally want the lower half of this screen to be just a number pad that is always up. There is no text box. Rather, as the user is punching in numbers, it'll be displayed in a textblock (a lot like you'd see in a calculator app). I'm not seeing a control for this and google just keeps bringing me back posts about InputScope. I was even thinking of maybe a hack-around where there's an invisible textbox that always has focus, causing the numberpad to always be up, but I don't even know how to cause that behavior either.

Is there a control or technique for this or am I going to have to roll a new user control? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating your own custom control. That would be the best solution for your condition. There is no inbuilt solution for this situation. I was stuck in the same condition and created a new control with a custom keyboard and a textblock.

And for the hack you mentioned. You can register the LostFocus event of the textbox control and focus the control again using Focus() method of Textbox everytime is loses focus.

Comment: I ran with the LostFocus method that you mentioned before you responded and it sorta works except I can't get the textbox to take focus when the view first loads. Once it takes focus, it's good, however. I tried setting focus OnNavigatedTo and in the ctor - neither seemed to work.

Comment: Try adding the focus method on Loaded event of the textbox. It should work.